# Throttling async calls made from actors

Tags: c#, akka.net

We have a fairly high throughput actor system which makes async calls to external systems over http. We are finding that the downstream systems are being overwhelmed due to the number of calls they receive from us.

The calls to the downstream systems are made using the "pipe to" pattern described here: https://petabridge.com/blog/akkadotnet-async-actors-using-pipeto/

The reason so many calls are made to the downstream systems is because an actor doesn't wait for the response from the async call to come back before it processes the next message in its mailbox (it is finished with the message when the async call is kicked off). Obviously this is by design, but in these cases it's resulting in a very high number of async calls being made to the an external service.

We need a way of throttling the calls being made. I can think of a few possible solutions to this problem.

1. Execute the call to the external service synchronously by waiting on the task to complete. Set up a pool router for the actor which would basically be a way of throttling the amount of calls being made to this external service.
2. Use the ReceiveAsync method rather than Receive. This is basically exactly the same as option 1. On the petabride page I posted above though it say this about this method - "just don’t do it" :)
3. Before making the async call, start stashing any incoming messages and then unstash them after the async task completes. Obviously using this method throughput is much more limited.

I was wondering if anyone out there has had a similar issue when working with  akka and was able to solve it?

**Edit:**

So in the end it was only option 1 that worked for us. I.e. having a pool router with a Receive() that specifically waited on IO calls it needed to make (an api call to an external system). This seems to work quite well and we can control the 'throttling' by setting the pool size.

We tried option 2 (ReceiveAsync) but what we found was that at some point the system would grind to a halt and become unresponsive without throwing any errors. We suspect it was getting itself into a deadlock situation. This would be due to the way the async keywork works vs simply waiting on a Task using .Wait() or .Result. I can now see why Petabridge recommend not to use ReceiveAsync :)

We didn't try option 3 as this would have meant more significant changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me, I've solved this with a use of creating sub-actors with a router as workers, that can process only one message at a time. So you can configure a load of external system with a number of workers. Also, this can give you the ability to use consistent hashing to avoid parallel processing of certain messages.

As for workers - in one project I've used the 1-st way, but used pinned dispatcher for workers - so they always have the same thread to process messages and just don't affect other system parts. This is good if you have a rather constant load.

Comment: Thanks for replying, it sounds like we are approaching this in a fairly similar way to yourself which is good... Will post an answer here later once we work out what works for us.

Answer (score 2):

Actually a second option (`ReceiveAsync`) is perfectly valid solution for your problem. The only risk is that in this case you're slowing the sender, as actor will now wait asynchronously for HTTP request to complete. This mean that the actor itself may be overwhelmed, if a high rate of messages will continue to push on it constantly.

If this is the case, you can either:

1. Increase the number of consumers (listeners on the other end of HTTP connection) to keep up with the pace.
2. Model your problem using Akka streams instead of actors. Streams have built-in support for backpressure, which can be applied upstream until it reaches the original source of the request trace.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are going to try out ReceiveAsync with a pool router and do some load testing to see how it goes. If that doesn't work well for us might have a look at Akka Streams.